# How to map values and add in R?

Tags: r

I have a table for cost of all items.

```
cost_table<- data.frame(FRUIT,COST)
                                      FRUIT   COST
1                                     APPLE   15
2                                    ORANGE   14
3                                      KIWI   13
5                                    BANANA   11
6                                   AVOCADO   10
```

and customer table where the corresponding cost of of the items have to be added.

```
   customer_name     items                           
1  sam               APPLE,AVOCADO                   
2  anna              ORANGE,KIWI,BANANA                    
3  elle              ORANGE                      
5  john              AVOCADO,APPLE                 
6  greg              KIWI
```

The items is of type list.
how do I map the items to cost table and add to get the total cost?

I want the output to be like this.

```
   customer_name     items                   total_cost        
1  sam               APPLE,AVOCADO           25       
2  anna              ORANGE,KIWI,BANANA      38              
3  elle              ORANGE                  14   
5  john              AVOCADO,APPLE           25     
6  greg              KIWI                    13
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cost_table <- read.table(text = "                                      FRUIT   COST
1                                     APPLE   15
2                                    ORANGE   14
3                                      KIWI   13
5                                    BANANA   11
6                                   AVOCADO   10", header = TRUE)

customer_table <- read.table(text = "   customer_name     items                           
1  sam               APPLE,AVOCADO                   
2  anna              ORANGE,KIWI,BANANA                    
3  elle              ORANGE                      
5  john              AVOCADO,APPLE                 
6  greg              KIWI                  ", header = TRUE)

# Calculate the max number of items in the customer_table
nmax <- max(stringr::str_count(customer_table$items, "\\,")) + 1

# Split the "items" into separate columns, reformat the data, and summarise COST
customer_table %>%
  separate(items, sep = ",", into = paste0("item_", seq_len(nmax)), fill = "right") %>%
  pivot_longer(-customer_name, values_to = "FRUIT") %>%
  left_join(cost_table, by = "FRUIT") %>%
  group_by(customer_name) %>%
  summarise(COST = sum(COST, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   customer_name  COST
#>   <chr>         <int>
#> 1 anna             38
#> 2 elle             14
#> 3 greg             13
#> 4 john             25
#> 5 sam              25
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you need the output ordered the same as the input you can convert "customer_name" to an ordered factor, e.g.

```
# Split the "items" into separate columns, reformat the data, and summarise COST
customer_table %>%
  mutate(customer_name = factor(customer_name,
                                levels = customer_table$customer_name,
                                ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  separate(items, sep = ",", into = paste0("item_", seq_len(nmax)), fill = "right") %>%
  pivot_longer(-customer_name, values_to = "FRUIT") %>%
  left_join(cost_table, by = "FRUIT") %>%
  group_by(customer_name) %>%
  summarise(COST = sum(COST, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   customer_name  COST
#>   <ord>         <int>
#> 1 sam              25
#> 2 anna             38
#> 3 elle             14
#> 4 john             25
#> 5 greg             13
```

---

### Edit

If your "items" column is a list you can use unnest, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

cost_table <- read.table(text = "                                      FRUIT   COST
1                                     APPLE   15
2                                    ORANGE   14
3                                      KIWI   13
5                                    BANANA   11
6                                   AVOCADO   10", header = TRUE)

customer_table <- tibble(customer_name = c("sam", "anna", "elle", "john", "greg"),
                             items = list(c("APPLE","AVOCADO"), c("ORANGE","KIWI","BANANA"),
                                          c("ORANGE"), c("AVOCADO","APPLE"), c("KIWI")))

# Split the "items" into separate columns, reformat the data, and summarise COST
customer_table %>%
  mutate(customer_name = factor(customer_name,
                                levels = customer_table$customer_name,
                                ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  unnest(items) %>%
  rename("FRUIT" = "items") %>%
  left_join(cost_table, by = "FRUIT") %>%
  group_by(customer_name) %>%
  summarise(COST = sum(COST, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   customer_name  COST
#>   <ord>         <int>
#> 1 sam              25
#> 2 anna             38
#> 3 elle             14
#> 4 john             25
#> 5 greg             13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: what has to be changed if the items is of type list ?

Comment: You will probably want to use [`unnest()` from the tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) to handle that case.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what to do if the items column is a list @AnushaN

Answer (score 0):

You could `strsplit` the items `by` customer at the comma, subset the cost table and `sum` the values. The `trimws` accounts for possible whitespace before or after the comma.

```
transform(customers, total_cost=unclass(
  by(items, customer_name, \(x)
     sum(with(cost_table, COST[FRUIT %in% trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ',')))])))))
#   customer_name              items total_cost
# 1           sam      APPLE,AVOCADO         38
# 2          anna ORANGE,KIWI,BANANA         14
# 3          elle             ORANGE         13
# 5          john      AVOCADO,APPLE         25
# 6          greg               KIWI         25
```

---

*Data:*

```
customers <- structure(list(customer_name = c("sam", "anna", "elle", "john", 
"greg"), items = c("APPLE,AVOCADO", "ORANGE,KIWI,BANANA", "ORANGE", 
"AVOCADO,APPLE", "KIWI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "6"))

cost_table <- structure(list(FRUIT = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "KIWI", "BANANA", 
"AVOCADO"), COST = c(15L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: can you please suggest a way to resolve the error I am getting, which says  " \(x)" as invalid input.

Comment: @AnushaN Yes, update your R or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Comment: and for '\\W" ?

Comment: @AnushaN Just leave it as is, it's a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: I am getting 
Error: '\W' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\W"

Comment: @AnushaN Did you use two backslasehs `\\W`?

Comment: yes I did use '\\W'

Comment: @AnushaN What if you use `strsplit(x, ',')`, i.e. splitting at the comma?

Comment: should the number of rows (in cost_table and customers) be equal for this solution to work?

Comment: @AnushaN No, the code basically just looks up the prices in the cost table. Does it work?  BTW are all `items` in the `FRUITS`?

Comment: Error in tapply(seq_len(1L), list(`customers$customer_name` = 2:1), function (x)  : 
  arguments must have same length
if i reduce customers i am getting this.
yes, all items are present in fruits

Comment: @AnushaN I checked that before and actually works fine for me. Could you add a small example top your question where it fails?